# Postgres (psycopg2) prevent user from changing runtime configuration parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to make a connection completely readonly for users to run queries against a schema in my database. While the user only has the SELECT permission in the tables in my_schema, I am still able to run `SET {param}` in a cursor. It persists and the next query with another cursor has the new parameters.

I have tried using `psycopg2.set_session(readonly=True)` to no avail. I cannot find information on revoking this permission on the user with the psql terminal, so I suspect it is connection specific. However, I still cannot find any information on doing this with psycopg2.

```py
import psycopg2

readonly_conn = psycopg2.connect(READONLY_DATABASE_URL)
cur = readonly_conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SET search_path TO my_schema,public")
cur.close()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-set.html):

> SET only affects the value used by the current session.

A session probably equals to one TCP connection, and it can "contain" multiple cursors.

Comment: if you're asking how to make postgres disallow 'SET'-ing of parameters: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/263955/can-postgres-restrict-usage-of-the-set-and-show-commands

Comment: Looks like there's no way to restrict it then. Would it make sense to rollback or commit after each transaction? I'd probably rollback as I don't want the `SET` to change the value for every cursor after. I've just tested it and it seems to work, not sure how efficient it is though.

Comment: from the docs again: "PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it." 
So it's possible that the performance loss will be negligible.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've actually found something else in the docs that more directly answers the question: "If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back. Once the surrounding transaction is committed, the effects will persist until the end of the session, unless overridden by another SET." So looks like I have to rollback to discard the changes.

Comment: It is important to read the entire section. Immediately after above is: 'The effects of SET LOCAL last only till the end of the current transaction, whether committed or not.'

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If you look at my question, I used `SET`, which is equivalent to `SET SESSION`. I may be missing your point though, could you elaborate?